# what does 'self.variable = self' means in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As far I know in python 'self' represents the object of a class. Recently I found a code where in the constructor(`__init__`) a variable value is assigned to 'self' like below:

```
self.x = self
```

Can anyone please explain what kind of value is actually assigned to x?

Comment: You're literally setting an object's attribute to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a circular reference. `self` is bound to the instance on which the method is called, so setting `self.x = self` just creates a reference to the instance on the instance.

This is a generally silly thing to do, and potentially harmful to the memory performance of your program. If the class also defines the [`object.__del__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) then this will prevent the object from being garbage collected, causing a memory leak in all CPython releases < 3.4 (which implements [PEP 442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/)):

```
>>> import gc
>>> class SelfReference(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.x = self
...     def __del__(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> s = SelfReference()
>>> s.x is s   # the instance references itself
True
>>> del s      # deleting the only reference should clear it from memory
>>> gc.collect()
25
>>> gc.garbage # yet that instance is *still here*
[<__main__.SelfReference object at 0x102d0b890>]
```

The `gc.garbage` list contains everything the garbage collector cannot clean up due to circular references and `__del__` methods.

I suspect that you found one of the very few actual usecases for assigning `self` to a an attribute anyway, which is the [usecase davidb mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28857532): setting `self.__dict__` to `self` if `self` is a mapping object, to 'merge' attribute and subscription access into one namespace.

Comment: Thanks Martijin for such a nice explanation. Its all clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this kind of assignments can generally seem not a good idea, yet there are cases where it is indeed useful and elegant.
Here is one of those cases:

```
class Dict(dict):
    '''Dictionary subclass allowing to access an item using its key as an
       attribute.
    '''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

Here is a simple usage example:

```
>>> d = Dict({'one':1, 'two':2})
>>> d['one']
1
>>> d.one
1
```

Comment: Right, but this is a *very special exception*. :-)